# Add Subview - Monotouch

Tags: iphone, ios, garbage-collection, xamarin.ios, addsubview

I have a MonoTouch tab view application.  On one of my tabs, when a user clicks a button, I want to show another view.  I do this with the following code:

```
UIView.BeginAnimations("flip");
UIView.SetAnimationDuration(1);
UIView.SetAnimationTransition(UIViewAnimationTransition.FlipFromRight, View, true);

NewFilesViewController newFilesViewController = new NewFilesViewController();
newFilesViewController.View.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(View.Frame.Top, this.View.Frame.Left, this.View.Frame.Width, this.View.Frame.Height);

View.AddSubview(newFilesViewController.View);
UIView.CommitAnimations();
```

On the new view, when I click a button, I get an error:

```
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
```

Should I be adding the view to the window instead?  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely (the code does not have enough context to be 100% sure) because `newFilesViewController` is not referenced anywhere later in the code. As such it can be disposed the next time the Garbage Collector (GC) is invoked. However the native code still except the *view* to exists and this will crash when it tries to call the (disposed) instance.

**Fix:** Promote your `newFilesViewController` local variable to a field. That will keep the reference alive (as long as the type's instance is alive) and the GC won't collect it.